# Find the longest file name in Linux

Tags: linux, io-redirection

I am searching for the longest filename from my root directory to the very bottom.

I have coded a C program that will calculate the longest file name's length and its name.

However, I cannot get the shell to redirect the long list of file names to standard input for my program to receive it.

Here is what I did:

```
ls -Rp | grep -v / | grep -v "Permission denied" | ./home/user/findlongest
```

findlongest has been compiled and I check it on one of my IDE's to make sure it's working correctly. No run time errors were detected so far.

How do I get the list of file names into my 'findlongest' code by redirecting stdin?

Comment: Your pipeline is unnecessary. Additionally, you will typically see "Permission Denied" -type messages being written to stderr, not stdout. Are you just after the longest *filename* (e.g: `findlongest`)? Or the longest *filepath* (e.g: `/home/user/findlongest`)?

Comment: I'm after the longest filename. I have excluded entries from the list of filenames but every time I try to redirect the list of filenames to stdin, they display a bunch of error messages saying "Permission denied", along with "cannot open directory"

Comment: Don’t vandalize your posts.

Comment: As an aside, the "Permission denied" messages are being printed to standard error, so the `grep -v` in the middle is not doing anything useful.

Comment: Really this is the wrong site to ask this (SO is about programming and this isn't programming). [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93111/find-files-by-the-length-of-filename) has a good answer to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
find / -type f | /home/user/findlongest
```

It will list all files from root with absolute path and print only those files you have permissions to list.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```sh
find / -type f -printf '%f\n' 2>/dev/null | /home/user/findlongest
```

The `2>/dev/null` will discard all data written to `stderr` (which is where you're seeing the 'Permission denied' messages from).

Or the following to remove the dependancy on your application (from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24509/how-to-print-the-longest-line-in-a-file)):

```sh
find / -type f -printf '%f\n' 2>/dev/null | \
    awk 'length > max_length {
           max_length = length; longest_line = $0
         }
         END {
           print length(longest_line) " " longest_line
         }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the command:

```
find -exec basename '{}' ';'
```

which prints recursively only the filenames of all the files starting from the directory you are: all the filenames.

This bash line will provide the file with longest name and the its number of characters:

Note that the loop involved will make the process slow.

```
for i in $(find -exec basename '{}' ';'); do printf $i" " && echo -e -n $i | wc -c; done | sort -nk 2 | tail -1
```

By parts:

Prints the name of the file followed by a single space:

```
printf $i" "
```

Prints the number of characters of such file:

```
echo -e -n $i | wc -c
```

Sorts the output by number of characters and takes the longest one (the very latest):

```
sort -nk 2 | tail -1
```

All this inside a for loop to handle line by line.

The `for` sentence can be also changed by:

```
for i in $(find -type f -printf '%f\n');
```

As stated in @Attie's answer

Comment: This is all sorts of inefficient, and will be slow. Primarily making the `find`utility fork and execute another utility for *every single file* in your filesystem is going to make things painfully slow - prefer `find`'s `-printf` flag (see my answer). Additionally, the `for` loop, the use of *many, many* instances of `wc`, and the invocations of `sort` and `tail` are far better suited to something like `awk`.